# Webservice to receive an external push

Tags: php, symfony, web-services, soap, push

I need a little guide please. An external application will send to my webapp several times a day this info (push in my application). My app is developed in php with symfony3 as framework). 
The information I will receive will be something like this (soap definition):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Header/>
 <soap:Body>
 <RoomRateListUpdRequest>
 <RoomRateListUpdRQ Language="es" Version="1">
 <Login User="hdynastic" Password="Dynastic2017" HotelCode="1">
 </Login>
 <RoomRateListUpd>
 <Contracts>
 <Contract id="104595" DateFrom="2019-08-03" DateTo="2019-08-03">
 <Rates>
 <Rate DateFrom="2019-08-03" DateTo="2019-08-03">
 <Rooms>
 <Room RoomTypeID="440">
 <Allotments>
 <Allotment AllotmentDate="2019-08-03" IsAvailable="true">98</Allotment>
 </Allotments>
 </Room>
 </Rooms>
 </Rate>
 </Rates>
 </Contract>
 </Contracts>
 </RoomRateListUpd>
 </RoomRateListUpdRQ>
 </RoomRateListUpdRequest>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What kind of webservice should I create to read this type of information? How to listen & receive this soap definition?

Thank you very much for any help provided!

Comment: PHP's [SoapServer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php)?

Comment: Soap server? Do you know an onlune example for this? I need to develop a soap server in my webapp to listen this kind of info? I  only understand that the external app will send me several times a day this info...a content <soap:Envelope xxxxx. Thanks!!

Comment: Since they send you info, you need to set up a web service, which in this case is the Soap Server. Then they consume the service (sending requests to it). Sure, you can most likely parse the request manually, but if they change something in the structure, your code might break. Using a Soap Server to handle that for you will help. Soap is horrible as it is (just my opinion.) Google something like: _"implement soap server php"_ and you should find some guides/tutorials.

Comment: Ok! A lot of thanks!! Now I understand I need to implement my soap Server and publish my function... this function will be called from the external app and this app will push in my soap service this info with this definition <soap:Envelope xxxx and more info about rooms. Yeah! I can process this receives content manuallly parsing this info.

Comment: Ok I can process this received content manuallly parsing this info. Another question please..This external app send me also some schema definition, like this:  Rates /Main element / Mandatory......Rate/Main element/Mandatory.....
Id/Rate code to update/Optional...
DateFrom/Start date /Mandatory xxx with this info can I parse this manually...or is there another alternative to process this info...alternative for parser?